# How to transpose in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with the following format

```
a 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0   
a 2 5 6 7 0 0 0 0  
a 4 5 9 0 0 0 0 0  
b 5 5 9 0 0 0 0 0   
b 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to end up with something like this

```
a 2  
a 3  
a 4  
a 2  
a 5  
a 6  
a 7  
a 4  .....  
b 1  
b 1   
b 1 ....
```

Comment: Where is your effort? Some code? Any tries?

Comment: I dont really know where to begin.  I was thinking of creating a macro. I used this formula to get all the data (after the first column in rows)   =INDEX(Sheet10!$B$2:$DN$657,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS(Sheet10!$B$2:$DN$657)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS(Sheet10!$B$2:$DN$657),COLUMNS(Sheet10!$B$2:$DN$657))+1)  Then I wanted to use a vlookup to get the letter it matches to.  However there are dups and this will not work.  i.e. a maps to 5 and so does b

Comment: Any particular order you need it in?

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [unpivot add-in](http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/the-unpivot-add-in/) (just add a header row that you can remove afterwards). It will return the data in the format you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub move()

    Dim cell As Range, _
        found As Range
    Dim letter As String

    Set cell = Range("B1")
    Set found = Range("A:A").Find("*", Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(2, 0)

    Do While (cell.Value <> "")
        letter = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Do While (cell.Value <> 0)
            found.Value = letter
            found.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
            Set cell = cell.Offset(0, 1)
            Set found = found.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        Set cell = Cells(cell.Row + 1, 2)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this pretty quickly with a combination of concatenation and de-concatenation and a formula from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TableToColumn.aspx

```
=$A1&","&B1
```

[image: Ex1]

```
=OFFSET($K$1:$R$5,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($U$1))/COLUMNS($K$1:$R$5),0),MOD(ROW()-ROW($U$1),COLUMNS($K$1:$R$5)),1,1)
```

[image: Ex2]

```
=LEFT(U1,FIND(",",U1,1)-1)
```

[image: Ex3]

```
=RIGHT(U1,FIND(",",U1,1)-1)
```

[image: Ex4]

Good Luck.